# C# Where statement Nullable vs Non Nullable

Tags: c#

I have a query which is returning the results of the following database table:

[image: Ticket table]

The query that i'm running is working. However, i only want to return the results of where the SiteID is equal to the ***SiteID*** that the user is allowed to see.
This is defined in the next table:

[image: SiteMembership]

Now, my query is as followed:

```
User user = ObjectContext.Users


        .Include("TeamMemberships")
            .First(u => u.UserID == userID);

        var teamIDs = user.TeamMemberships.Select(t => t.TeamID).ToList(); //This returns the Users team (Not important for now)
        var siteIDs = ObjectContext.SiteMemberships.Where(t => teamIDs.Contains(t.TeamID)).Select(t => t.SiteID).ToList(); //This returns the SiteIDs that the user is allowed to see

        int? ticketID = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) == false)
        {
            if (text.StartsWith("#"))
                text = text.Substring(1);

            int temp;
            if (int.TryParse(text, out temp))
                ticketID = temp;
        }

        var tickets = ObjectContext.Tickets
          .Include("TicketPriority")
          .Include("TicketStatu")
          .Include("TicketType")
          .Include("TicketCategory")
          .Include("Server")
          .Include("Site")
          .Include("Detector")
          .Include("Detector.Site")
          .Include("Detector.Track")
          .Include("Team")
          .Include("User")
          .Include("User1")
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? t.TicketID == ticketID.Value : true)
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? true : t.StartedOn >= fromDate && t.StartedOn <= toDate)
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? true : ticketStatusID.HasValue ? ticketStatusID.Value == 100 ? t.TicketStatusID < 4 : t.TicketStatusID == ticketStatusID.Value : true)
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? true : ticketPriorityID.HasValue ? t.TicketPriorityID == ticketPriorityID.Value : true)
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? true : ticketCategoryID.HasValue ? t.TicketCategoryID == ticketCategoryID.Value : true)
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? true : createdByUserID.HasValue ? t.CreatedByUserID == createdByUserID.Value : true)
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? true : assignedToTeamID.HasValue ? t.AssignedToTeamID == assignedToTeamID.Value : true)
          .Where(t => ticketID.HasValue ? true : assignedToUserID.HasValue ? t.AssignedToUserID == assignedToUserID.Value : true);
            if (ticketID.HasValue == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) == false)
                tickets = tickets.Where(e => e.Title.Contains(text));

            return tickets.OrderBy(t => t.TicketID);
```

Now, What i tryed to do was add an extra .Where statement like:

```
.Where(t => siteIDs.Contains(t.SiteID));
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> The best overloaded method match for ... has some invalid arguments.

Is this error generated because i compare a non-nullable value to a nullable value or has this to do with something else?

Comment: if you compare nullable to non nullable `int a; int? b; if(a ==b.Value)` So it is possible, that `siteID` is nullable .`Where(t => siteIDs.Contains(t.SiteID.Value));`

Comment: Wauw... i feel so stupid for now trying that / forgetting it :/    
But it is working! Thank you very much :)